# How do I get template updates to show

Tags: theming

I'm sure this is a very simple fix, but I'm new to Drupal and would be very appreciative if someone could help. I have a theme that I am using on a Drupal site. I make some changes to the underlying text in the themes PhP files (e.g. "Page not found" -> "Page is not found!"). I then reload the page and I do not see the changes on the site. I have tried clearing Drupal's cache and then reloading, but this also doesn't seem to help. After I make changes to a theme, how do I get them to show up on the site?

Comment: It is most likely what you think your editing is not what your actually viewing, this is common if your not familiar with Drupal.

Comment: Show us a bit of code, its location, etc?

Comment: For example, I am trying to update the following block of code: <h1>The page cannot be found</h1> to <h1>The page cannot be found!</h1> which is located in /sites/default/themes/realia/templates/page--404.tpl.php. When I run "grep -rl "The page cannot be found" ." from the root directory, this is the only location that appears.

Comment: It seemed to be a caching info. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms you describe is usually due to some caching happening. Make sure you've turned off *all* caching in Drupal (sometimes, just clearing the cache isn't enough). Also, make sure that you clear your *browser's* cache (SHIFT+reload).